# Why are the estimates and other measures coming different each time the Markov Switching Model is run using MSwM package?

Tags: r, time-series

I was exploring $\mathsf{MSwM}$ package for applying Markov Switching $\mathsf{AR}$ model; for that I used the $\textrm{example}$ dataset which has been used for illustrating the usage of the package.

One peculiar and conspicuous thing that I noticed is that in every run, the summary was changing (though not drastically). For example

```
 data("example") 
 mod = lm(y~x, example)
 
 mod.mswm = msmFit(object = mod, k = 2, sw = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = 1, control = list(parallel = FALSE))
 summary(mod.mswm)
```

Running twice $\mathsf{mod.mswm}$ and subsequently $\mathsf{ summary(mod.mswm)}$ yielded

```
    Markov Switching Model

Call: msmFit(object = mod, k = 2, sw = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = 1, 
    control = list(parallel = FALSE))

       AIC     BIC    logLik
  637.0736 693.479 -312.5368

Coefficients:

Regime 1 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   0.8417     0.3023  2.7843  0.005364 ** 
x(S)            -0.0533     0.1333 -0.3998  0.689304    
y_1(S)           0.9208     0.0305 30.1902 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5034675
Multiple R-squared: 0.8375

Standardized Residuals:
          Min            Q1           Med            Q3           Max 
-1.5153664458 -0.0906543666  0.0001873641  0.1656717253  1.2020899012 

Regime 2 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   8.6393     0.7254 11.9097 < 2.2e-16 ***
x(S)             1.8771     0.3107  6.0415 1.527e-09 ***
y_1(S)          -0.0569     0.0798 -0.7130    0.4758    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9339683
Multiple R-squared: 0.2408

Standardized Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.31102193 -0.03317757  0.01034139  0.04509107  2.85245599 

Transition probabilities:
           Regime 1   Regime 2
Regime 1 0.98499728 0.02290885
Regime 2 0.01500272 0.97709115
```

```
#Another run

Regime 1
---------
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)(S) 0.8417 0.3025 2.7825 0.005394 **
x(S) -0.0533 0.1340 -0.3978 0.690778
y_1(S) 0.9208 0.0306 30.0915 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Residual standard error: 0.5034675
Multiple R-squared: 0.8375
Standardized Residuals:
Min Q1 Med Q3 Max
-1.5153666657 -0.0906543311 0.0001873641 0.1656717256 1.2020898986

Regime 2
---------
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)(S) 8.6393 0.7244 11.9261 < 2.2e-16 ***
x(S) 1.8771 0.3107 6.0415 1.527e-09 ***
y_1(S) -0.0569 0.0797 -0.7139 0.4753
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Residual standard error: 0.9339683
Multiple R-squared: 0.2408
Standardized Residuals:
Min Q1 Med Q3 Max
-2.31102193 -0.03317756 0.01034139 0.04509105 2.85245598
Transition probabilities:
Regime 1 Regime 2
Regime 1 0.98499728 0.02290884
Regime 2 0.01500272 0.97709116
```

If observed carefully, the transition probabilities are different and that for various regimes, even though the estimated coefficients matched, the t values, errors were slightly different; the min, Q1 etc. also changed slightly.

Then I tried to impose $\mathsf{AR}(1)$ with $3$ regimes without $x$ exogenous variable.

```
  mod = lm(y~1, example)
  mod.mswm = msmFit(object = mod, k = 3, sw = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = 1, control = list(parallel = FALSE))
  
  summary(mod.mswm)
```

Running twice yielded

```
     Markov Switching Model

Call: msmFit(object = mod, k = 3, sw = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = 1, 
    control = list(parallel = FALSE))

      AIC      BIC   logLik
  658.032 714.4373 -323.016

Coefficients:

Regime 1 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   1.8479     0.5038  3.6679 0.0002446 ***
y_1(S)           0.7903     0.0552 14.3170 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4825552
Multiple R-squared: 0.7842

Standardized Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-1.521915859 -0.010057548  0.004799415  0.150095435  0.827505274 

Regime 2 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   9.0144     1.0350  8.7096   <2e-16 ***
y_1(S)           0.0046     0.1132  0.0406   0.9676    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.077642
Multiple R-squared: 2.306e-05

Standardized Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.72531714 -0.03769462  0.01142456  0.05914606  2.67087220 

Regime 3 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   0.3774     0.4064  0.9286   0.3531    
y_1(S)           0.9879     0.0406 24.3325   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3899546
Multiple R-squared: 0.9145

Standardized Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.52941087 -0.12828562 -0.01439866  0.03764457  0.88746100 

Transition probabilities:
            Regime 1     Regime 2   Regime 3
Regime 1 0.803210661 3.798663e-05 0.19697603
Regime 2 0.000136034 9.753744e-01 0.03207687
Regime 3 0.196653305 2.458759e-02 0.77094710
```

```
Markov Switching Model

Call: msmFit(object = mod, k = 3, sw = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = 1, 
    control = list(parallel = FALSE))

       AIC      BIC    logLik
  660.3768 716.7821 -324.1884

Coefficients:

Regime 1 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   0.6538     0.2932  2.2299  0.02575 *  
y_1(S)           0.9658     0.0299 32.3010  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.340833
Multiple R-squared: 0.9281

Standardized Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.37156498 -0.19286528 -0.01162027  0.02641217  0.85630408 

Regime 2 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   1.0635     0.5156  2.0626  0.03915 *  
y_1(S)           0.8503     0.0526 16.1654  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3841655
Multiple R-squared: 0.8772

Standardized Residuals:
          Min            Q1           Med            Q3           Max 
-1.1304413713 -0.0004873064  0.0303579711  0.1941870186  0.3273787794 

Regime 3 
---------
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)(S)   9.0130     0.9263  9.7301   <2e-16 ***
y_1(S)           0.0050     0.1010  0.0495   0.9605    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 


Residual standard error: 1.07911 Multiple R-squared: 2.68e-05
Standardized Residuals: Min Q1 Med Q3 Max -2.72730666 -0.04842395
0.01472835 0.08210111 2.66862749
Transition probabilities: 
       Regime 1   Regime 2   Regime 3 
Regime 1 0.6138586 0.601289531  0.025735963
Regime 2 0.3611760 0.393378818 0.001482911 
Regime 3 0.0249654 0.005331651 0.972781126
```

This time the changes were more prominent: AIC, BIC, Loglik were different as $(660.3768, 716.7821, −324.1884)$ against $(658.032, 714.4373 ,− 323.016);$ the
estimates came different here.
In all, the differences were not too stark and drastic but it is incomprehensible to me as to why all these get changed each time the model is run. How
come estimates of model get changed each time they are calculated? Or is there
anything in the theory of the Markov Switching models that makes it happen?
Would be grateful if somone sheds light on this bizzare behavior of this package.

- Why do each run of the model yield different measures? What's the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior.

Fitting this type of model is a relatively difficult optimization problem. Most optimization algorithms refine their current solution iteratively until they find that they can't refine it further, but they have to start from somewhere. Starting from a random value is a common way of doing this.

Here, this is done by first randomly assigning observations to regimes (from `MSwM:::.MSM.lm.msmFit`):

```
ind=sample(1:k,length(object$residuals),replace=T)
```

Then, coefficients can be estimated on each regime, new regime assignments can be computed, and so forth, as the EM algorithm continues its work. This is where the randomness comes from, that initial random assignment to regimes.

Typically, if you wanted to be really sure that you had found a good optimal value, you would start from multiple different random starts and choose the final result that gave the best likelihood. Also, note that the actual regime index is immaterial, so from run to run it's quite possible that what used to be called "regime 2" is now called "regime 3", but that doesn't have any real impact.

Finally, if you want some level of reproducibility, you can set the RNG seed (`set.seed`) before fitting the model.